# Asp.Net MVC Validators passando pelo controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html5, validação, jquery-validate

Quando criamos um projeto em Asp.Net ele por padrão insere alguns validadores para serem usados com o Razor, `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.property)`.

Vi em diferentes projetos que estas mensagens são geradas através do retorno do `controller`, ou seja, quando o formulário é enviado, ele verifica o `ModelState` e de acordo com a resposta, traz os campos obrigatórios e assim "ativa" a mensagem para o que esta faltando, porém, já vi também em alguns projetos que ele não necessita entrar no `controller` para realizar a verificação, o que eu preciso saber é o que define esta situação.

O que faz o validador antes de entrar no `controller` saber quais os campos são necessários serem preenchidos?

**EDIÇÃO:**

Acho melhor inserir os *javascripts* que realizam as validações e também os demais que uso para sabermos se algum esta atrapalhando o outro.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/template/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    @*USAR NESTA ORDEM*@
    <link href="~/Content/template/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-confirm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/meucs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>angular.module("Angular", []);</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/tecbox/MainController.js"></script>    
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criei um formulário com o seguinte em Razor:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataNascimento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataNascimento, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker", size = "16" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataNascimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Isto gera o seguinte HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="DataNascimento">Data de Nascimento</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control datepicker hasDatepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="O campo Data de Nascimento deve ser uma data." data-val-required="O campo Data de Nascimento é obrigatório." id="DataNascimento" name="DataNascimento" size="16" type="text" value="" aria-required="true">
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="DataNascimento" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Repare que tem várias anotações começadas por "data-" e por "aria-". [A especificação de `WAI-ARIA` está aqui](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/). [Sobre `data-` tem alguma coisa aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp). [O jQuery Validation utiliza estes atributos pra saber o que validar](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/). É por isso que a requisição nem vai para o *Controller*: o JS realiza alguma validação e só depois ele permite que o formulário seja finalmente enviado.

Experimentei não passar uma data de nescimento no formulário. Veja o que aconteceu:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="DataNascimento">Data de Nascimento</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control datepicker hasDatepicker input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-date="O campo Data de Nascimento deve ser uma data." data-val-required="O campo Data de Nascimento é obrigatório." id="DataNascimento" name="DataNascimento" size="16" type="text" value="" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="DataNascimento-error">
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="DataNascimento" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span id="DataNascimento-error" class="">O campo Data de Nascimento é obrigatório.</span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Várias coisas foram trocadas sozinhas.

Normalmente, para usar com ASP.NET MVC, a seguinte inclusão já deixa tudo pronto pra você.

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

O *Bundle* fica da seguinte forma:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Comment: isso quer dizer que não precisam ser inseridas as propriedades nos elementos html na mão, certo? Pois tenho um outro projeto aqui que funciona, apenas não consigo achar o problema. Estão praticamente iguais.

Comment: Certo. Você apenas decora os atributos. O resto o *framework* faz por você.

Comment: Alguma coisa esta errada, ineri um breakpoint no controller e ele ainda esta sendo chamado.

Comment: Então passou para o *Controller*, ou você configurou errado seu projeto.

Answer (score 1):

As validações que são realizadas no client com o ASP.Net MVC utilizam o JQuery Validation (https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation).

Nesse caso, validações mais simples como required por exemplo conseguem ser feitas no browser antes que sejam realizadas pela Controller.

Comment: Eu já realizei as modificações necessárias, porém não adiantaram. Vou editar a pergunta com a sequencia atual de scripts renderizados para que possamos identificar o problema.